# Anyone up for [modified] questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modified) seems ripe for burnination. If community agrees with this suggestion then manual retagging would be a better approach as only 86 questions use this tag.

Comment: It's crazy how many of those are exact duplicates with different answers.

Comment: What's the standard way of "voting" in favor? ;) or am I such n00b that my opinion is not to be counted? (Honestly, that would be fair)

Comment: @NathanDortman Meta is weird. Voting on the question (burninate-request is like feature-request where voting is for expressing agreement/disagreement). Also comment or answer if you have anything to add.

Comment: If there are indeed just 86 of them, why bother?

Comment: @PM77-1 they are 86 today, could become 860 next year. Some users (specially new users) want to use as many tags as possible. If usage of meta/invalid tags is not stopped during early usage it becomes very tough to remove them later.

Comment: Its slow but the count is going down. Currently at 66

Comment: The trouble with [modified] is that it is used to modify exactly one of the other tags, and you may guess which...

Comment: The modified tag brings nothing useful to the question, burn it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also agree but for different reasons: As a new user I look at it and I see it has no description (Wiki Summary) and that makes it very vague and arguably not helpful. Its hard to see how people can meaningfully use this tag.

Comment: If you can figure out what it's good for (seems to be everything modified / midifiable or stats about that) and the tag is good (that's an *emphatic no*), all users are welcome to add a good wiki / add a missing one.

Answer (score 12):

I agree as it is also quite narrow. Questions of such usually has similar context and falls into alike behaviour, making questions of such tag similar and mostly duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean it is narrow? For tags, being specific is not neccessarily a detriment, unless its excessive.

Comment: @Deduplicator While the tag is accurate and specific, it's _narrow_ as questions involving "modified" has similar context, and "modified" is not a dynamic descriptor.

Comment: Given that it doesn't have description or wiki at all, I find it difficult to judge whether it is narrow or not. It's ambiguous so for that reason it should go.

Answer (score -7):

obviously get rid of it.

Could there be some sort of **automatic system** like this:

"if less than (say) 100 uses in more than (say) 24 months, autoroboburninate with no discussion or mention"

Comment: there a lot of tags that are not active but are not meaningless like this tag.